# Is there a way to delete a string copied to the clipboard in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, clipboard

```
val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("String", variable)
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

I am using the method of copying a string to the clipboard as above.
But if I press the button several times, the clipboard will fill up unnecessarily

I want to delete a string with the same label from the clipboard and then copy it again.
What should I do?

+Edit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbPkW.jpg)

Too many strings are copied like this image.
I want to leave just one string of images that look like blocks.
Is there no way to delete the string in the clipboard?

Comment: Can you give an example of the behavior you want?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it......., but I've added an image. Does it look ok?

Comment: Hmmm.... If I express it like code, I would like to have a function like ClipData.deletePlainText("String")